# Need help binding parameters without question marks

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to update a row using prepared statements. I don't want to use question marks because it escapes all apostrophes. I am trying to bind it using :coloumn_name

When I tried i keep on getting this error message...

Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object....

Can someone please try to help me correct this. I have included my code below. Thanks!

```
    $query = "UPDATE categories SET category_name = :category_name WHERE id = :id ";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param(":category_name,:id", $category_name, $id);
```

Comment: MySQLi does not support named placeholders, it _only_ allows `?`.  If you want named placeholders, consider switching to PDO, which is easier to use anyway.

Comment: Here is very nice tutorial to learn [pdo](http://a2znotes.blogspot.in/2014/09/introduction-to-pdo.html)

Comment: [**Use PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) if you don't want to use question marks.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it this way with `mysqli`.

Only PDO (with prepared statements), supports named placeholders.

For more information, visit the PHP.net Website:

- **http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements**